# psql COPY from STDIN and a pipeline from echo

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I am using Postgresql 9.5. In my code, I need to create a pipeline to extract the data and insert into a database. To test the pipeline with psql, I created a table in the database: employee(name,dept,jobtitle), and used the command:

```
echo -e "Paul,IT,Manager\n\." | psql -U *** -h localhost -d *** -1f copy.sql
```

The file of copy.sql is as follows:

```
COPY employee (name,dept,jobtitle) from STDIN WITH(FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', HEADER FALSE)
```

The result of the command is:

```
COPY 0
```

I guess the psql parser recognises no lines from the input. Is it because the wrong format of echo input? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---

I also tried to COPY from csv file, using the \copy command. It succeeded. The command used is

```
psql -U *** -h localhost -d *** -1f copy_file.sql
```

copy_file.sql is:

```
\copy employee (name,dept,jobtitle) from '/path/to/csv/file' WITH(FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', HEADER FALSE)
```

The csv file is

```
Paul,IT,Manager
\.
```

Comment: I tested it because it is an interesting problem. If you add "verbose" (-v) to your original psql command you will see error message. Problem is with pipeline - with pipeline psql ignores "-f" parameter and therefore also COPY command in file and takes all input only from pipeline. It worked when I used `echo -e "$(cat copy.sql)\n...data..." | psql ....`

Comment: Just guess: when `psql` executing a script file it assuming that the data coming just after `copy ... from stdin ...` command and sending it to the `copy` instead of the "actual" stdin. You can execute `copy ... from ... stdin` command using `-c` option of the `psql` - it should to work.

Comment: @JosMac Good point. I added "-v VERBOSITY verbose" and got no error. I donot think that with pipeline psql ignores "-f" parameter, as the result is "copy 0", which means that psql "saw" the COPY command. The reason may be that with "-f" paramter psql ignores the STDIN input. Can you share the complete code of `echo -e "$(cat copy.sql)\n...data..." | psql ....`?

Comment: @Abelisto Good point! The following codes work: `echo "Paul,IT,Manager" | psql -U postgres -h localhost -d bedrock -1c 'COPY employee (name,dept,jobtitle) from STDIN WITH(FORMAT CSV, HEADER FALSE)'`. I guess it assumes that the -f parameter is not compatible with the STDIN.